# Mouse Accelerators for Visual Studio commands

Tags: mouse, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am looking for a way to tie Visual Studio commands to mouse-key combinations.  In particular, I'd like to tie Go to Definition to the mouse-key combination Ctrl-LeftClick.  This is a fairly common pattern from Visual Assist and Resharper, however for performance reasons, I have had to disable both of those things and am living with the IDE base set for now.  But being able to tie any command to any combination of key+mousebutton would be highly desirable.

I'd be curious in an VS extension or other way of doing this.  An external app, perhaps?

Comment: I have a gaming mouse and just bound F12 to one of the extra buttons, but I'd still be interested in a solution for the Modifier-Click usage pattern.